# log4net traceappender only logs messages with level 'verbose' when using Windows Azure DiagnosticsMonitor

Tags: c#, azure, log4net, azure-diagnostics

I have an azure worker role which I have configured to use a log4net Trace Appender which writes to WindowsAzure.Diagnostics. This is done by making the following calls in the RoleEntryPoint of the worker role.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics;
using log4net.Config;

namespace XXX
{
    public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {
        public override bool OnStart()
        {
            var config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();

            config.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Warning;
            config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

            config.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("System!*");
            config.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("Application!*");
            config.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Error;
            config.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

            DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", config);

        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        }
    }
}
```

The App.config file is configured in the following manner:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%logger - %message" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>

<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
        <listeners>
            <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

The result of this is that all messages (even errors) are logged in table storage as "verbose" level.

How to fix this?

Comment: This is now out of date. See http://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/10/22/logging-with-log4net-and-azure-diagnostics-on-web-and-worker-roles/ for example.

Comment: Are you sure? People still seem to be experiencing this issue with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics 2.5.0.0

Comment: hmmm :/ no i'm not sure.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A couple of blog posts deal with this issue: ([here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/05a82e48-e706-43ca-9364-80aa14784618) and [here](http://www.dotnetsolutions.co.uk/blog/windows-azure-diagnostics---why-the-trace-writeline-method-only-sends-verbose-messages))

- **It turns out that the log4net TraceAppender converts all log messages
  to Trace.Write messages and that the DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener converts all Trace.Write messages to verbose.**

The answer in my case was to use Pete McEvoy's solution and extend the TraceAppender in the following manner:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Core;
namespace XXX.Logging
{
    public class AzureTraceAppender : TraceAppender
    {
        protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            var level = loggingEvent.Level;
            var message = RenderLoggingEvent(loggingEvent);

            if (level >= Level.Error)
              Trace.TraceError(message);
            else if (level >= Level.Warn)
              Trace.TraceWarning(message);
            else if (level >= Level.Info)
              Trace.TraceInformation(message);
            else
              Trace.WriteLine(message);
            if (ImmediateFlush)
              Trace.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

This extension was then implemented in my App.config:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="AzureTraceAppender" type="XXX.Logging.AzureTraceAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%logger - %message" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="AzureTraceAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Very useful. However, I was not getting debug level messages from log4net via `Trace.Write()`. I adjusted the code to `else if (level >= Level.Debug)` and am now seeing debug level messages in my streaming logs and table storage.

Comment: Yes it was very useful. One comment: a simple Trace.Write(..) will not show in Azure streaming log, so the final else branch does nothing. We must project the 5 levels of log4net messages to explicitly the 3 levels of Trace.

Comment: I have `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics 2.5.0.0`, but still the same issue. Your answer solved it though.

Comment: as @g.pickardou pointed out, Trace.Write() does not show in azure streaming log.  However, Trace.WriteLine() does show up as logging at the verbose level.  5 log4net levels to 4 azure levels is much easier than going to 3 azure levels

Comment: @g.pickardou & josh : TraceAppender code updated. Thanks for pointing it out.